# stdout and stderr of parallel computation in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, stdout, stderr

I am using the package `parallel` to do computation. Here is a toy example:

```
library(parallel)
m = matrix(c(1,1,1,1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2), nrow=2)
myFun = function(x) {
  if (any(x<0.5)) {
    write("less than 0.5", stderr())
    return(NA)
  } else {
    write("good", stdout())
    return(mean(x))
  }
}
cl = makeCluster(2, outfile="/tmp/output")
parApply(cl, m, 2, myFun)
stopCluster(cl)
```

The problem is both the stdout and the stderr will be redirected to `/tmp/output`. The `output` file looks like this:

```
starting worker pid=51083 on localhost:11953 at 11:37:12.966
starting worker pid=51093 on localhost:11953 at 11:37:13.261
good
good
less than 0.5
less than 0.5
```

Is there any way to setup two separate files for the stdout and the stderr, respectively? and how to ignore the first two lines of "starting worker pid=..."?

Answer (score 5):

The `parallel` package doesn't directly support sending stdout and stderr to separate files, but you can do it yourself:

```
cl = makeCluster(2)

setup = function(outfile, errfile) {
  assign("outcon", file(outfile, open="a"), pos=.GlobalEnv)
  assign("errcon", file(errfile, open="a"), pos=.GlobalEnv)
  sink(outcon)
  sink(errcon, type="message")
}

shutdown = function() {
  sink(NULL)
  sink(NULL, type="message")
  close(outcon)
  close(errcon)
  rm(outcon, errcon, pos=.GlobalEnv)
}

clusterCall(cl, setup, "/tmp/output", "/tmp/errmsg")
parApply(cl, m, 2, myFun)
clusterCall(cl, shutdown)
```

Since the "starting worker" messages are issued before `setup` is called, those messages are redirected to "/dev/null", which is the default behavior when `outfile` isn't specified.